# Use cakePHP and ReactPHP combination, is this possible?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, reactphp

Is it possible to run cakePHP application and reactPHP as its web-server? I heard a huge performance gain by using reactPHP. However, I have not seen anyone have leverage on existing matured PHP framework such as cake.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I don't have the time to write a proper answer right now, but you can check out **http://slides.com/wyrihaximus/getting-started-with-reactphp-cakfest-2016** (**https://github.com/WyriHaximus/cakephp-reactphp-cakefest2016**) for something to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

We've implemented a Bridge for PHP-PM (based on ReactPHP) here https://github.com/CakeDC/cakephp-phppm

The plugin manages the bootstrapping and handling of an application request, and some experimental benchmarks proved that, in specific applications, it would provide a substantial performance boost (2x requests/second).